# VSTS GitHub Pull Request Trigger Not Firing

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-devops, pull-request

I can't seem to get my VSTS build to trigger for GitHub pull requests. It works fine when i commit to the `master` branch, but not when i open the pull requests to the `master` branch.

Here's the screenshot from VSTS:
[image]

I can also see the 2x Webhooks in GitHub:
[image]

I can see the `pull_request` webhook fires successfully when i open a PR too (returns 200 ok), but VSTS doesn't seem to be triggering the build.

I'm guessing there's something obvious i've missed. Can someone help please?

Comment: If you enables the PR Validation for github repo master branch, vsts build should be triggered automatically. Please check with below opeations: create a PR in github -> then check the build definition summary page -> if the latest build is build for `refs/pull/number/merge` (like the https://imgur.com/a/cnSlc), that means PR validation is triggered successful.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @NPadrutt yes, it was a bug with VSTS, which they fixed. If you're still having issues might be a different problem

Comment: @RPM1984 I guess I found something yesterday. They deactivated this due to security concerns. The last update was, that they plan to reactivate it in April 2018

Answer (score 0):

As auto trigger is enabled only for master branch, I would suggest you add one more branch filter. Click on the add button and include other branches also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to trigger it for any PR's to master..i don't care what the branch name is. So, i tried adding `*` as the branch filter, but it still didn't work..

Comment: Hi,
Don't add ```*```, the filter in the PR trigger specifies the PR target branches, not the source ones.